# ruby- method_missing return no method error

Tags: ruby

I am trying to use method_missing to convert dollar to different currencies.

```
class Numeric
    @@currency={"euro"=>2, "yen"=>6}
    def method_missing(method_id,*args,&block)
        method_id.to_s.gsub!(/s$/,'') #get rid of s in order to handle "euros"
        @@currency.has_key?(method_id) ? self*@@currency[method_id] : super             
    end
end

> 3.euro   #expect to return 6
NoMethodError: undefined method 'euro' for 3:Fixnum
from (pry):24:in 'method_missing'

> 3.euros  #expect to return 6
NoMethodError: undefined method 'euros' for 3:Fixnum
from (pry):24:in 'method_missing'
```

I guess `3.euro` isn't working because `:euro.to_s.gsub!(/s$/,'')` returns `nil`. I am not sure why it returns no method error.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When *method_missing* will be called, then `euro` will be assigned to the `method_id` as a **symbol**. But your `@@currency` hash holds all keys as a strings, you need to convert them as **symbols**.

`method_id.to_s.gsub!(/s$/,'')` no way will change the actual object `method_id`. Because `method_id.to_s` will give you a new *string* object, and `#gsub!` will work on this only. No way you are changing the `method_id`, it remains as it is. Better to use *non-bang* one, because it will give you the actual object if no change made, or changed object, if change is made, then you need to assign this return value to a new variable.

With your `@@currency`, `@@currency.has_key?(method_id)` evaluated as `false` and `super` class  `method_missing` has been called. Why? As `method_id` didn't convert into strings, which you expected may happened.

But, if you want to respond for both like `euro` or `euros`, then

```
class Numeric
    @@currency={"euro" => 2, "yen" => 6}
    def method_missing(method_id,*args,&block)
        #get rid of s in order to handle "euros"
        new_method_id = method_id.to_s.gsub(/s$/,'') 
        @@currency.has_key?(new_method_id) ? self*@@currency[new_method_id] : super             
    end
end

3.euros # => 6
3.euro  # => 6
```

Comment: And that will modify immutable symbols?

Comment: @PlatinumAzure No `:sym.to_s` gives you completely new string object 'sym'. Thus now if you use bang method like `#gsub!` on `'sym'`, there shouldn't be any effect on `:sym`. `a = :sym
a.to_s.sub!('s' ,'d') # => "dym"
a # => :sym`.

Comment: @PlatinumAzure Thanks for your appreciation and time to re read my answer. Thank you very much!

Comment: You could further improve the answer by removing the first code snippet, which is still technically wrong. :-)

Comment: @PlatinumAzure I am always hungry to improve myself. Thanks for your further comments... You have the liability to correct me always if I am wrong..

Answer (score 1):

`gsub!` modifies a string in place and returns `nil`. That won't work very well with the string you're using, which is a temporary created by `to_s` and never stored in a variable. Also, you are not even storing the result anywhere anyway. Why should `gsub!` on a string be expected to modify symbols, which are immutable anyway?

Try using `gsub` instead, which returns the modified string and leaves the caller alone. You'll also need to store the return value.

```
real_method_name = method_id.to_s.gsub(/s$/, "")
```

Also: The reason `3.euro` didn't work is because your hash uses strings as keys but `method_id` is passed to the method as a symbol. If you didn't have to do string manipulations (to remove s suffixes, in this case), I would have suggested to just use symbols as your hash keys. As it is, though, you need to do string operations anyway, so my answer uses strings.

Comment: That's one issue. It doesn't explain why `euro` doesn't work, though.